# What is a solution to css rotatez in the html2div plugi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

here is the css Im using to rotate the image

```
'-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
'-moz-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
'-o-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
'transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
```

According what I read on the subject you must rotate the image using JavaScript BEFORE using the canvas2html . I have to find a way to turn the above css into JavaScript to rotate an image using the html2div plugin. The problem is that I'm using sliders to rotate the image and I have no idea how to convert this into JavaScript to work with the UI slider can someone give me a starting point?
http://jsfiddle.net/davadi/3d3wbpt7/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily without any plugin

First select the element you want to rotate and save it as a JavaScript variable:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
```

Then change the transform attribute like this:

```
element.style.transform = 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)';
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have to rotate the image on a canvas like this ` 
ctx.rotate( 90*Math.PI/180 );`

Comment: @user1119742 maybe you can edit your question to be more specific.  The original question doesn't mention using canvas; canvas is entirely different.

Comment: hi and thanks for you response. Basicliy what Im trying to do is rotate an image using jquery Ui on a canvas and I have to do this because Im building a web app that uses the html2canvas plugin and this plugin does not support css rotate and I  must rotate the image using JavaScript before I use the html2canvas plugin